# Unity Container same type name but from different Namespaces

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have to build a unity container to inject dependencies in my asp.net project. In that project, I have to register two types which are from different namespaces but have the same name. So how can I register both types into one unity container?

```
container.RegisterType<IType, Type>()
container.RegisterType<IType, Type>();
```

Here ITypes and Types are from a different namespace. But have the same names. So how can I register both in one container? I'm using Unity Container version 5.2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used Unity, but assuming it's the same as any other container, it should be as simple as this:

```
container.RegisterType<NamespaceA.IType, NamespaceA.Type>()
container.RegisterType<NamespaceB.IType, NamespaceB.Type>();
```

Essentially, types will be registered internally using their [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) metadata, so the container will see them as two completely separate types, just as if they were called `ITypeA` and `ITypeB`.

Then when you inject them, you just have to make sure you're referencing the correct namespace.

If you need both of them, explicitly reference both namespaces:

```
public MyService(NamespaceA.IType aType, NamespaceB.IType bType)
```

Or, if you only need one, then simply reference the namespace with a `using` (or explicitly) and inject it as normal:

```
using NamespaceA;

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IType aType)
    {
    }
}
```